# Magento 2.3 customer form register template file override

Tags: magento2, template-override

I am working on Magento 2.3 version. I have create custom module for the override the register.phtml file but it is not working. I have provided some files details

> Kh/Registration/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Kh_Registration" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> Kh/Registration/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Kh_Registration::form/register.php</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

> Kh/Registration/view/frontend/templates/form/register.php

```
<h1>New registration file </h2>
```

I have **`enable module`**, **`clear cache`** but it shows core magento file

> **vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml**

Please advice me

Answer (score 2):

If you using magento 2.2.X  and greater then

**then you can use**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register"  template="Kh_Registration::form/register.phtml"/>
</body>
</page>
```

Also, you have to ensure   `Magento_Customer` load fast then `Kh_Registration` is loading, So please check `Config.php` at `app/etc/` .if not then you need to need to run setup upgrade command and it will update module sequence as you have `added` `<sequence>` at module.xml.

Also,as Kishor Hase said, you  template file extension should be `.phtml` NOT `.php`

Answer (score 2):

There are two way the override the template in the custom module....

**First :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Kh_Registration::form/register.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

**Second :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register"  template="Kh_Registration::form/register.phtml"/>
</body>
</page>
```

The way I posted in the question/below is not working because, according to issue [#3356](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3356) on the Magento 2 GitHub repo, there are a number of cases where the method won’t work.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Kh_Registration::form/register.phtml</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: Is this working now

Answer (score 1):

It should be **`.phtml`** not **`.php`**:

```
<argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Kh_Registration::form/register.phtml</argument>
```